# Checkbox persistence issue on page load in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, dom-events

I want to save the check-boxes state in the checked state on page-load or refresh using the local storage session of the Firefox or IE browser. I am using the local storage concept in Javascript in jsp page to accomplish this.

Each of the check-boxes are associated with folders **(having specific and distinct folder ids)** so, only the check-boxes which are in checked state should be saved in local storage. Here in first code it is defining the state of the check-box and the checklist[count] which saves the ids in array  form of specific folders [in case of multiple selection of check-boxes as per the (CODE 1).

a) How can I pass the specific checked ids of the check-boxes to the `window.onload=function()` in my  code so that the selected folder items only maintain the checked state on page refresh or load  in the (CODE 2)? Please suggest.

Comment: So, do you want get the id's of selected checkbox inside onload function?

Comment: I want to keep the check-box in checked state for my on load function.I want to save the state of the check-boxes which are in checked state. The reason I mentioned the id in my thread is,every check-box has a folder adjacent to it and the folder id will help to distinguish between the selected check boxes.I am storing the ids in an array here checklist[count] = array_ids; Can you please suggest your thoughts on where I need to change my above code to accomplish this?

Comment: I am also calling my check-box function in the onload of the page so that the checkbox actions are maintained in the same way as defined in the function checkbox() once the page loads. I have fetched the session value in onbeforeload() page function. Any thoughts how i can rectify it?